# Request for article in Rev. Roumaine Math. Pures Appl. (1981)

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, paper-request

I am looking for the following article:
Al-Hussaini, A. N. A projective limit view of $L_1$-bounded martingales.
Rev. Roumaine Math. Pures Appl.26 (1981), no.1, 51–54, but I can't find it anywhere.

Do you know where I can find this article?

Comment: it is not available online, interlibrary loan seems your only option.